# What is Auto-Sklearn Dummy Model?

Tags: scikit-learn, automl

When I apply AutoSklearn for some datasets I get this error

```
No models better than random - using Dummy Score
```

What does it mean? what is this Dummy Model?

How does it do classification/predictions?

Answer (score 1):

Dummy model is a model which predicts by purely guessing or using simple rule. E.g. for classification randomly assigns a class or just uses the majority class; for regression just uses the mean. It serves as a basic benchmark and sanity check.

BTW, It is not an Auto-Sklearn specific thing.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a reference or a document I can read more about the dummy model?

Comment: Scikit-Learn's implementation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.dummy)